# Windows build number and correlation to KB number

Tags: windows-10

So the Fall Creators Update basically bricked my dev environment and I have lost several days of work due to it. Anyway, I need to roll back the updates but to a certain Windows build number. Really, I need at a minimum build 16176 and less than 16288. So I am trying to figure out the KB number so I know which updates to uninstall. Not sure if this would resolve the issue but worth a shot.

Just remembered too. The other option is I have a computer that doesn't have the Fall Creators Update and works fine. However it is below 16176. I could manually apply the updates to bring it to that build using:

http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=16176

But it only takes KB numbers. I don't know what KB = 16176.

This doesn't provide the KB numbers either:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/release-notes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I am trying to figure out the KB number so I know which updates to
>   uninstall.

Windows 10 Version 1609 had an intial build number of **16299.0** but **16299.15** was the actual first stable release build and the current revision of of build 16299 as of October 17 2017 is **16299.19**.  The KB that upgrades the initial **16299.15** build to **16299.19** is **KB4043961**.  The only way to uninstall a Feature Update is to revert to your previous version of Windows.  There isn't a KB associated with them.  There is no KB associated with **16299.15** only the ISO that was released around October 2nd 2017

> Really, I need at a minimum build 16176 and less than 16288.

If you want to revert back to build 16176 or 16288 it would mean reverting back to a Insider Preview RS3 build of Windows 10.  Insider Preview builds expire after a period of time.  At this point you would have to reinstall Windows 10 to revert back to one of those builds since the amount of time between **16288.1** or **16176.1000** and **16299.15** is greater then 15 days.

You might be able to revert to the previous version of Windows provided it's been less then 15 days since you install **16299.15** and/or **16299.19**

> Just remembered too. The other option is I have a computer that
>   doesn't have the Fall Creators Update and works fine. However it is
>   below 16176. I could manually apply the updates to bring it to that
>   build using:

This method will not work.

> But it only takes KB numbers. I don't know what KB = 16176.

There isn't one and the build numbers you want to use are Insider Preview builds of the Fall Creators Update so they also don't KB numbers associated with them.

- [10.0.16176.1000](https://changewindows.org/build/16176) was released back on April 14 2017
- [10.0.16288.1](https://changewindows.org/build/16288) was released back on September 12 2017
- All stable Windows 10 updates which change the build number can be found [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4043454)

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response. Sounds like I need to wait for an update to come out that fixes the issue. Thankfully I have this other computer so I can keep working. But yeah, the issue is WSL is broke, at least for me, when it comes to symlinks being created between the WSL and Windows mount, making it pretty much useless since there needs to be communication between the two.

Comment: You should if you already had WSL enabled, reset it and uninstall it, then reinstall since it not only went stable but how you install it has changed from 1703

Comment: Yeah have tried uninstall, reinstall, using `lxrun`, using the Windows Store, etc. Pretty much the same result among them. Followed the latest article on how to install it. Trying to do `npm install` or `virtualenv` onto the `/mnt/c` results in permission errors that seem to be related to symlinks between the two. Issues didn't exist before the update.